# extracting data with different columns from different rows from pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to extract data from dataframe by selecting different columns and different rows. For example, I want 3rd column data from row 1-100 and 2nd column data from row 101-200. I am currently using for loop but would be nice if there is any faster option.

```
low_data =[]
up_data = []

for i in range(200):

    low = df.iloc[i,2]
    up = df.iloc[i,1]

    low_data.append(low)
    up_data.append(up)
```

Comment: `low_data = df.iloc[0:100,2]` and `up_data = df.iloc[100:200,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you coud create your indexer:

```
ix = np.array([np.arange(100), np.arange(100, 200)]).T
iy = np.array([[1, 2]])
```

and the values are then

```py
df.values[ix, iy]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: glad I could help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question - you want to extract rows 1 to 100 from column 3, and also extract rows 101-200 from column 2.

If this is the case, this can be achieved more simply by (assuming all starting from 0 index):

```
low_data = df.iloc[0:100, 2] # return rows 0-99 from col 2
up_data = df.iloc[100:200, 1] # return rows 100-199 from col 1
```

You may find  the "slicing ranges" section of the documentation useful (about halfway down): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Thank you, but I may not explain the question clear enough.